# Selenium Failed to start Socket listener

Tags: selenium

I am starting selenium server.

After i enter java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b2.jar in command prompt, i am getting following

[image]

See the 11th line(6th from bottom), which is saying Failed to start Socket listener.

What does it means? and How to start it ?

Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to kill the process that is using that port. You more than likely improperly closed Selenium the last time, and the process is continuing to run.

You can run `netstat -ab` in cmd to check the process that is using that port. More then likely going to be java.exe

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the most innovative approach in this case is to simply reboot your test machine. This should clear any rogue instances of the Selenium server running on the port.